# It’s a great honor to have your visit/ It’s a great honor to have you visit me?

Tags: sentence

I was looking for an expression to use when a person receives the visit of someone important, and I found these two:
1 It’s a great honor to have your visit.
2 It’s a great honor to have you visit me. 
Which one is more natural ? Thanks.

Comment: Are they really visiting you specifically? If they are visiting a big group you are a part of, it seems weird to use 'me' (implying they were there for you in particular).

Comment: Yes, this person is visiting me specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To have you visit me** seems to be the most used, it also seems the most natural to me personally. For information about the use of both phrases in books over time, consider [this ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+you+visit+me%2Cto+have+your+visit&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20you%20visit%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20have%20your%20visit%3B%2Cc0)